# Android: Set Text To Check Box Not Working

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to set the text of a Check Box from an Edit Text but it's not working.

I've created an Edit Text with a Button that when clicked creates a Check Box and gets the text for the Check Box from the Edit Text. The app crahes when I click on the Button.

XML

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_task"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="New Task"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Create" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

JAVA

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootContainer);
            EditText newTask = findViewById(R.id.text);

            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);

            String task = newTask.getText().toString();
            newTask.setText(task);
            checkBox.setText(task);

            // Add Checkbox to LinearLayout
            if (linearLayout != null) {
                linearLayout.addView(checkBox);
            }

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace or the error you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` of EditText in your layout is `android:id="@+id/new_task"`

whereas in Activity you using

`EditText newTask = findViewById(R.id.text);`

So you should use same id in Activity as in xml

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line from onClick event

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootContainer);
```

and add that line in `onCreate()` method.

Because **linearLayout** is your root container.

you don't need to find every time.

And same for the button.

Also there is issue related id. 
You are finding `text` id but you mentation `new_task` in xml.

So below line should be `EditText newTask = findViewById(R.id.new_task);`